# Servlet JSP with AJAX and JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I've been doing my school project for a while, but my login page, doesn't seem to be working.

It always gives me a PARSING ERROR as shown:
[Error Login AJAX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqXZQ.png)

For my login i use a simple servlet, connected to sql-server database.
In the servlet side, i checked in debug mode.. everything is working.
This is the servlet code:

```
package servlets;

 import DAO.Model;
 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


 public class login extends HttpServlet 
 {
 private static PrintWriter out;
 private static String message;
 private static Gson gson;
 private JSONObject simpleJO;
 Model model = null;

 public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(conf);

    ServletContext ctx = conf.getServletContext();
    String URL = ctx.getInitParameter("DB-URL");

    model = new Model(URL);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    simpleJO = new JSONObject();
    gson = new Gson();
    String usernameStudente = request.getParameter("usernameStudente");
    String emailDocente = request.getParameter("emailDocente");
    String mansioneUtente = request.getParameter("mansioneUtente");
    String passwordUtente = request.getParameter("passwordUtente");

    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    out = response.getWriter();

    System.out.println("Username: " + usernameStudente);
    System.out.println("Password: " + passwordUtente);
    System.out.println("Mansione: " + mansioneUtente);

    if(mansioneUtente.equals("Studente"))
    {
        if(model.loginStudenti(usernameStudente, passwordUtente))
        {
            simpleJO.put("status",true);
            simpleJO.put("error", "Login Studente Success");
        }
        else
        {
            simpleJO.put("status",false);
            simpleJO.put("error", "Login Studente Failed");
        }
    }
    else if(mansioneUtente.equals("Docente"))
    {
        if(model.loginDocenti(emailDocente, passwordUtente))
        {
           simpleJO.put("status",true);
           simpleJO.put("error", "Login Docente Success");
        }
        else
        {
            simpleJO.put("status",false);
            simpleJO.put("error", "Login Docente Failed");
        }
    }
    message = gson.toJson(simpleJO);
    System.out.println(message);
}

}
```

**This instead is my javascript file:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#mansioneUtente').change(function()
{
    if($('#mansioneUtente').val() == 'Studente')
    {
        $('#usernameStudente').attr('disabled',false);
        $('#emailDocente').attr('disabled',true);
    }
    else if($('#mansioneUtente').val() == 'Docente')
    {
        $('#usernameStudente').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#emailDocente').attr('disabled',false);
    }

}).trigger('change');

$('#btnLoginUtente').click(function()
{
    processUserLogin();
});
});

function processUserLogin()
{
var sdata = {
    mansioneUtente: $('#mansioneUtente').val(),
    usernameStudente: $('#usernameStudente').val(),
    emailDocente: $('#emailDocente').val(),
    passwordUtente: $('#passwordUtente').val()};

$.ajax(
{
    url:'login',
    type:'POST',
    data: sdata,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.status === true)
            alert(data.error);
        else
            alert(data.error);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,data) 
    {
        alert("JQXHR: " + jqXHR + " TEXT STATUS: " + textStatus + " ERROR THROWN: " + errorThrown + " DATA: " + data);
    }
});
}
```

As you can see, in the alert, it gives me : *data undefined*. 
Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, you have mentioned the expected data type to be **JSON**.

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

However your servlet is not returning anything.  That is the reason for your undefined data.

The solution is to make your servlet return a JSON data.
Have `@ResponseBody` annotation on top of your function.  Bind your desired data onto the response object in JSON format.

```
JSONObject jsonObj      = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("ObjName", yourObject);
response.setContentTyp("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```